# ¿Cómo ejecutar línea de código cuando termine proceso?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema:

Tengo las siguiente líneas de código:

```
ObtDatos("listarClienteA.php", acCliente, cliente);
acCliente.setText(cliente);

//se ejecute otra linea pero esperando a que se ejecute obtDatos
```

Este el código de **ObtDatos**:

```
public void ObtDatos(String PHP, final AutoCompleteTextView ac, final String cliente){
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        String url = dominio  + PHP;

        RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();

        client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    CargarLista(ObtDatosJason(new String (responseBody)), ac, cliente);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            }
        });
 }
```

Como es **Async** tiene un tiempo de ejecución, la aplicación pasa directamente a la siguiente linea, como no termino de ejecutar me sale una excepción con `cliente` que esta en valor `null`. Cuando `ObtDatos` se termina de ejecutar genera un valor a `cliente`. Alguien puede ayudarme o alguna sugerencia, estaba pensado en colocar unos segundos de retardo pero lo mas conveniente sería esperar a que se ejecute las lineas de código

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema, pero lo que querés que pase después de obtener los datos debería estar dentro del onSuccess(). Entiendo que ese callback se llama cuando la llamada asincrónica termina bien y te trae los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes implementar semaforos, estos bloquearan la la ejecución hasta que exista un release

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
```

```
final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
try{

        client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    CargarLista(ObtDatosJason(new String (responseBody)), ac, cliente);
                }
                semaphore.release();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        });
        semaphore.acquire();
    }catch(Exception e){
        semaphore.release();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pon la variable acCliente `public Static`  posteriormente, en el if ya al cargar los datos, manda llamar la variable Estática desde tu if y se debería actualizar, 
en dado caso que la variable acCliente sea un control por ejemplo un Label, entonces tendrías que realizar una copia y manipular la copia en la función:

```
TextView acCliente =(TextView) .....
copiaacCliente =  acCliente;
```